# Update list and adapter from outer class

Tags: android

I am building a chat app.In `Oncreate` I am connecting to my server with this method:

```
public void connectToJabber(String username,String password) {
    Intent jService=new Intent(this,ConnectionIntent.class);
    jService.putExtra("type", "login");
    jService.putExtra("username",username);
    jService.putExtra("password",password);
    startService(jService);
}
```

You see,this is a service.This is my `ConnectionIntent` service:

```
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Connection connection=((Trackers)getApplication()).getConnectionInstance();
        String process=intent.getExtras().getString("type");

        if (process.equals("login") == true) {
            //Login İşlemleri
            String username=intent.getExtras().getString("username");
            String password=intent.getExtras().getString("password");
            try {
                connection.login(username,password);
            } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
...
```

You see I am using `connection` variable for connect.And I am getting this variable from `Connection` class.

In `Connection` class I have a message listener class.When I receive a message it is coming to this method:

```
    public class ListenMessages implements MessageListener {  
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat arg0,
                org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message arg1) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Received message:"+arg1.getBody()));  

        }  

    }
```

My problem is starting here.When I receive the message I have to add sender's name to chat list and I should update the adapter.But I defined chat list and adapter inside main activity.So I couldn't access it from `processMessage`.

What should I do for achive this ?

Comment: Are you sure you can use `catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e)` ? Isn't this a feature of Java 1.7? Android's Java is only 1.6.

Comment: It's working ? Not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need is a way to communicate between Service and Activity.

Mosten times I use Broadcasts for that matter(note, that there are variants that are local to your App), but there are also ways by binding the service etc.

**EDIT**

I cannot provide you with a complete example, but you can use the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to register a BroadcastReceiver (can be an anoymous class instance or an instance of an inner class) in your Activity and to broadcast Intents from your Service. Those indents will be received by the BroadcastReceiver. You can put any kind of data into the intents via extras and get them in the BroadcastReceiver for further use.

Comment: Can you give an example ? I have to update list and adapter when message arrives.

Comment: Please explain more,I am waiting your comment